# Terraform: how to use the results of the Lambda invocation somewhere else?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a lambda which is being invoked quite fine during `terraform apply` and I get good output from it:

```
output "out_params_map" {
  description = "something"
  value = module.get_params.result_map
}
```

it shows proper result

```
terraform apply...
...
Outputs: 

out_params_map = [
  {
    "key1" = "val1"
    "key2" = "val2"
  },
]
```

When I try to use the output somewhere else like this

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "this" {
  some_param = module.get_params.result_map.key1
}
```

both `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` fails:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on file.tf line 32, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "this":
  32:   some_param = module.get_params.result_map.key1
    |----------------
    | module.get_params.result_map is empty tuple

This value does not have any attributes.
```

I also tried:

```
... = module.get_params.result_map[0].key1
... = jsondecode(module.get_params.result)["key1"]
... = module.get_params.result_map["key1"]
```

but it does not work either.

More code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/rQaDJstU

**So, how to use the results of the invocation somewhere else?**

Comment: Can you show a fully workable [mcve] please? It's hard to see from the more minimal example you have here what could be wrong.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR With pleasure, but what part do you want to see? Full set will include lambda creation and I'm in doubth it makes sense. On the other hand, if I omit that part then the only code is resource as copy&pasted already.

Comment: How are you getting the `module.get_params.result_map`? Wherever that comes from is probably the useful part.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR added the link, pls let me know if more details needed.

Comment: @Putnik Were you able to find a solution for this? I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you define your output variable as V in module M, then you can access it as

> variable = "${module.M.V}"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. They already tried that as you can see by the error message.

Comment: in v0.12 you don't have to use "${..}", just variable name.